# Eclipse ADT plugin update error occurred when updating from ADT 16 to ADT 17.

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-indigo

I came across a terrible error while updating my android ADT plugin in Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2). Please check the image attached.

[image: Eclipse ADT 17 Update error]

Thanks

Comment: Yes i was also facing some problems while updating ADT plugin to 17. What i have tried? **1.** I had tried to update SDK-tools, platfrom-tools, support packages from SDK Manager. **2.** Then i went into the Eclipse, and click for "Check for update".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by my self. I just restart the machine.

Answer (score 4):

Faced similar issue. This is how I fixed it.

1.Downloaded ADT 17.0 Plugin zip file from http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html (do not unpack it).

1. In Eclipse got to Help >> Install New Software >> Add >> Archive and point to the Zip location on your local drive.
2. This should install the new Plugin.
3. Last but not the least... RESTART Eclipse..:-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using Helios 3.6.2 on Windows 7 64bit until I upgraded to Indigo.